# C# Regex: returning a collection of results

Tags: c#, regex

```
string: "<something><or><other>"
regex pattern: "<(\w+)><(\w+)><(\w+)>"
```

How do I make a regex call that returns to me a collection of results containing everything between the parentheses?  For example, I would want a result set of {"something", "or", "other"}.

For bonus points, what is this called?  Captures?  Capturing groups?  Some kind of templating?  I feel like if I knew the proper terminology I could search for it.

Thank you.

Comment: For those using the 'Matches' method: this method will match an ENTIRE regex pattern and return a collection of all matches of the entire pattern.  The question refers to individual capture groups which should be requested by using the Groups property of an individual Match object.

Comment: @Sid The question is ambiguous enough that either `Matches` or `Groups` should work fine. The OP asked to learn how to make a Regex call that returns "a collection of results containing everything between the parentheses", and either method satisfies this.

Comment: The 'Matches' method will not give you the requested results for any input pattern however.  A simple pattern like @"(\w+)(\d+)" would be significantly more code with the Matches method for the same output.  Also, he mentions captures and capturing groups, which should indicate that he's looking for the individual capture groups of a match and not the entire match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're typically referred to as capture groups, and you can get the captures as shown:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"some (pattern)");
Match m = regex.Match("some pattern");

foreach (Capture c in m.Groups)  {
  Console.WriteLine(c.Value); // write the value to the console "pattern"
}
```

`m.Groups.Count` will let you know how many groups matched, `m.Groups[0]` will always be the full match text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`MatchCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx):

> Represents the set of successful
>   matches found by iteratively applying
>   a regular expression pattern to the
>   input string.

**Example:**

```
string input = "<something><or><other>";
string pattern = "(?<=<)[^>]*(?=>)";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.ToString()); // do something with match here
}
```

**Edit:** Changed regex from this:
`<(\w+)><(\w+)><(\w+)>`
to this:
`(?<=<)[^>]*(?=>)`

Comment: Not quite, this gives me one match, for "<something><or><other>".  I want three matches, one for "something", one for "or", and one for "other".

Comment: @david I modified your Regex; try the example now. It should give you the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use MatchCollection.
EDIT: Forgot to change the regex to what you were requesting. The code below generates the following output:

something
or
other

Is that what you were looking for?

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = "<something><or><other>";
        var re = new Regex(@"(\w+)");
        MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(str);

        foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test
{
  class Test
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string target = @"<something><or><other>";

      // One group, many matches
      Regex r1 = new Regex(@"<(\w+)>");
      MatchCollection mc = r1.Matches(target);
      foreach (Match m in mc)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
      }
      Console.WriteLine();

      // One match, many groups
      Regex r2 = new Regex(@"<(\w+)><(\w+)><(\w+)>");
      Match m2 = r2.Match(target);
      if (m2.Success)
      {
        foreach (Group g in m2.Groups)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine();

      // One group, one match, many captures
      Regex r3 = new Regex(@"(?:<(\w+)>)+");
      Match m3 = r3.Match(target);
      if (m3.Success)
      {
        foreach (Capture c in m3.Groups[1].Captures)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine();

      // Many matches, no groups, no captures
      Regex r4 = new Regex(@"(?<=<)\w+(?=>)");
      foreach (Match m in r4.Matches(target))
      {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```